# Chromium mini installer size reaches 1.19GB?

Tags: c++, google-chrome, chromium

I am working on chromium and after successfully running the command:

```
ninja -C out\BuildFolder mini_installer
```

I get mini_installer.exe in the build directory, but the issue is that the mini_installer.exe size reaches 1.19 GB. I couldn't understand what's wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should be more specific. Give reproduction steps and details about your environment. Not just one isolated command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely a debug version of mini installer. You can modify the contents of `args.gn` to configure debug/release version, remove/add certain features, remove debug symbols from certain libraries etc. For example, the following GN arguments in `args.gn` file can be used to generate an optimized 64-bit mini installer:

```
is_debug = false

target_cpu = "x64" # x86 for 32-bit

remove_webcore_debug_symbols = true

is_official_build = true
```

If you have no plan to debug webcore then you should set `remove_webcore_debug_symbols` to `true`, as it will reduce the size of mini installer. Also setting the `symbol_level = 0` should make even smaller mini installer but remember, doing so will make debugging your Chromium fork almost impossible because of no debug symbols and highly optimized executable file. Also, for debug versions you should set `is_component_build = true` to enable faster linking but you should set its value to `false` for release builds to minimize the size of compiled executables, which will reduce the size of mini installer too.

Comment: Thanks a ton! It worked like a charm and the size of the mini_installer.exe is now 50MB only.